# How to send SIP messages using pjsua2 android

Tags: android, pjsip

I am trying to send messages with pjsua2. But it is throwing a exception. Please suggest me.

Here is my code

```
public void sendInstantMessage(String buddy_uri) {

    buddy_uri = "sip:aaaaa@xxx.yyyyyy.zzz";

    BuddyConfig cfg = new BuddyConfig();
    cfg.setUri(buddy_uri);
    cfg.setSubscribe(true);

    MyBuddy im = new MyBuddy(cfg);
    SendInstantMessageParam prm = new SendInstantMessageParam();        
    prm.setContent("Hi This is X, sending message");

    boolean valid = im.isValid();
    Log.e(TAG, "valid ======= "+valid);
    try {
        im.sendInstantMessage(prm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "sendInstantMessage ==== "+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }

}
```

It throwing a exception and here is log

```
05-27 15:42:40.705: E/SipApi(27611): valid ======= false
05-27 15:42:40.706: A/libc(27611): ../src/pjsua-lib/pjsua_pres.c:231: pjsua_buddy_get_info: assertion "pjsua_buddy_is_valid(buddy_id)" failed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the solution for sending SMS using pjsip-2.4

Here is the code

```
/**Send message to this number
 * @param String number
 * @param String msgBody*/
public void sendInstantMessage(String number, String msgBody) {
    String sipServer = "aaa.ggg.net";
    String buddy_uri = "<sip:" + number + "@" + sipServer + ">";

    BuddyConfig bCfg = new BuddyConfig();
    bCfg.setUri(buddy_uri);
    bCfg.setSubscribe(false);

    MyBuddy myBuddy = new MyBuddy(bCfg);
    SendInstantMessageParam prm = new SendInstantMessageParam();
    prm.setContent(msgBody);

    try {
        myBuddy.create(account, bCfg);
        myBuddy.sendInstantMessage(prm);
        myBuddy.delete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I used your code and I am using TLS server. but I am getting (501/Not implemented here)  so please let me know what I am missing. I am sending IM just after I am getting register event. so can you please elaborate what step should I follow.

Comment: @gangadhar how do you get the response after sending the message....whether message sent successfully or not ? any callback

Comment: yep there is a callback onInstantMessageStatus()

Comment: Hi how can i receive that mesage in pjsip pjsua2